# Number of combinations of bytes ordered by value

Tags: math, byte, combinations, permutation

I can't wrap my head around a mathematical question regarding combinations/permutations:

1 byte can store 256 possible combinations (2^8). 
2 bytes can store 65536 possible combinations (2^16). 
3 bytes can store 16777216 possible combinations (2^24).

This works only, because I have all possible combinations for each byte.
Given the requirement that the bytes need to be ordered by value – meaning byte<sub>1</sub> >= byte<sub>2</sub> >= ... >= byte<sub>n</sub> – how many combinations are there for 2, 3 or more bytes?

I'm pretty sure for 2 bytes there would be 32,896 combinations, which I got to with the following function: 
`(combinations * (combinations + 1)) / 2`

I have currently no idea how to adapt this to 3 or more bytes.

Comment: For 3 bytes it's (256 * (256+1) * (256+2)) / 6. For 4 bytes it's (256 * ... * (256+3)) / 24. For the general result, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that whether you impose `byte1 ≥ byte2 ≥ ...` or `byte1 > byte2 > ...` will change the result.

- For `byte1 > byte2 > ...`, with 256 different possible bytes, there are **(256 choose k)** different possible ordered sequences of distinct k bytes.
- For `byte1 ≥ byte2 ≥ ...`, with 256 different possible bytes, there are **(256 + k - 1 choose k)** different possible ordered sequences of k bytes.

Here (n choose k) is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

The result for `byte1 ≥ byte2 ≥ ...` can be proven using the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two).